# Livewire - Dependant Dropdown select

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have created a dependant dropdown with livewire like this:

```
class CreateAppointment extends Component
{
    public $doctorCategories;
    public $doctors;
    public $selectedDoctorCategory = NULL;
    
    public function mount(){
        $this->doctorCategories = Doctor_Categories::all();
        $this->doctors = collect();
    }
    
    public function updatedSelectedDoctorCategory($doctor_type_ID)
    {   
        if(!is_null($doctor_type_ID)){
            $this->doctors = Doctor_Categories::with('doctors')->find($doctor_type_ID); 
        }
    }
}
```

And this is in my blade file:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="doctor_categories" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Doctor Categories</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select wire:model="selectedDoctorCategory" class="form-control">
                          <option value="">Choose category</option>
                          @foreach($doctorCategories as $cat)
                              <option value="{{ $cat->id }}">{{ $cat->doctor_category }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
          
              @if (!is_null($selectedDoctorCategory))
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="doctor" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Doctor</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <select class="form-control" name="doctor_id">
                              <option value="" selected>Choose Doctor</option>
                              @foreach($doctors->doctors as  $doctor)
                                  <option value="{{ $doctor->id }}">{{ $doctor->name }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                          </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              @endif
          </div>
```

It works well but when i select "Choose category" again it throws an error saying attempted to read property doctors on null.How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, that livewire does not apply the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middlewares on its requests. This is [by design](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/823) and is not a bug. It can be reintroduced (see the comments to the linked issue) but I advise caution doing so. With select it should work fine, but with input it can mess things up.

Instead of checking for `is_null`, check for `empty` and you should be fine.